# Heroku error module not found 'json-server'

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, server, json-server

I want to deploy my server on Heroku, but on Heroku build it says this:

[image]

The app works fine locally, but somehow it crashes on the Heroku server.

This is the *file structure*
[image]

This is the *code for server.js*

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router('data.json');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

server.use(router);
server.listen(port);
```

This is *package.json*

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "json-server",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm install && node server.js"
  },
  "author": "japsuchiha",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.15.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pure guess, but I don't think heroku is installing json-server since it's listed under devDependencies

Comment: you are a savior! i didn't see that!

Comment: This fixed my issue too. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem was on cyclic.sh. You saved my day!